# SQL Server 2012: How to find common values in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012: How to find common values in a column

Please find below my exact requirement and help me with the Fine tuned query.
Please find below my exact requirement and help me with the Fine tuned query.
Please find below my exact requirement and help me with the Fine tuned query.

```css
  

Input :

select 1, 'sankar', 'GROUPLG'
union all 
select 1, 'sankar', 'GROUPLS'
union all 
select 1, 'sankar', 'GROUPNG'
union all 
select 1, 'sankar', 'GROUPNS'
union all
select 2, 'Srini', 'HYDRSPMLG'
union all 
select 2, 'Srini', 'HYDRSPMLS'
union all 
select 3, 'Ravi', 'AADSCLS'
union all
select 4, 'Arun',  'RREDFTLS'
union all
select 4, 'Arun',  'RREDFTNG'
union all
select 5, 'Raja',  '1234567'
union all
select 5, 'Raja',  'ABCDESLS'
union all
select 5, 'Raja',  'ABCDESLG'
union all
select 6, 'Dhilip',  'GGGGRASCDW_RV'


Output :

-- 1 Sankar GROUP(LG,LS,NG,NS)
-- 2 Srini  HYDRSPM(LG,LS)
-- 3 Ravi   AADSCLS
-- 4 Arun   RREDFT(LS,NG)
-- 5 Raja   1234567
-- 5 Raja   ABCDESLG(LG,LS)
-- 6 dhilip GGGGRASCDW_RV
```

Comment: Does your `groupname` always starts with `GROUP` and are they always 2 characters?

Comment: Hi Felix Pamittan, It wont be always start with 'GROUP' but it always ends with 'LG,LS,NG,NS' and also the length may get differ.

Comment: You should be redesigning your table now. You may find a solution to solve this for now, but trust me, this will come biting you. Learn the basic of normalization, then your life would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have succeeded by the below query which i have developed. Thanks for you all. If you want You can copy the below query and execute in SSMS.

```css
begin tran

Create table #temp (userid int, username varchar(50), groupname varchar(50))

insert into #temp(userid , username , groupname)
select 1, 'sankar', 'GROUPLG'
union all 
select 1, 'sankar', 'GROUPLS'
union all 
select 1, 'sankar', 'GROUPNG'
union all 
select 1, 'sankar', 'GROUPNS'
union all
select 2, 'Srini', 'HYDRSPMLG'
union all 
select 2, 'Srini', 'HYDRSPMLS'
union all 
select 3, 'Ravi', 'AADSCLS'
union all
select 4, 'Arun',  'RREDFTLS'
union all
select 4, 'Arun',  'RREDFTNG'
union all
select 5, 'Raja',  '1234567'
union all
select 5, 'Raja',  'ABCDESLS'
union all
select 5, 'Raja',  'ABCDESLG'
union all
select 6, 'Dhilip',  'GGGGRASCDW_RV'
union all
select 6, 'Dhilip',  'CDW_RV'
union all
select 6, 'Dhilip',  'GFNG'
union all
select 6, 'Dhilip',  'GFNS'
union all
select 7, 'Satya',    '184518451845'

select * from #temp

select tp.userid , tp.username, groupname + CASE WHEN tp.flag = 1 THEN  CASE WHEN ct.cnt > 1 then ' (' else '' end +         
                   ISNULL(pt.grouptype1,'')+case when grouptype2 is not null 
                               and grouptype1 is not null then ',' else '' end +
                   ISNULL(pt.grouptype2,'')+case when grouptype3 is not null 
                            and (grouptype1 is not null 
                            or   grouptype2 is not null ) then ',' else '' end +
                   ISNULL(pt.grouptype3,'')+case when grouptype4 is not null 
                            and (grouptype1 is not null
                            or grouptype2 is not null
                            or grouptype3 is not null) then ',' else '' end +
                   ISNULL(pt.grouptype4,'') + case when ct.cnt > 1 then ')' else '' end
           ELSE ''
           END as Permission

from (SELECT distinct userid , username, CASE WHEN RIGHT(groupname,2) IN ('LG','LS','NG','NS') THEN Substring(groupname,1,len(groupname)-2)
             ELSE groupname END as groupname ,
             CASE WHEN RIGHT(groupname,2) IN ('LG','LS','NG','NS') THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END as flag from #temp ) tp

--WHERE Substring(groupname,1,len(groupname)-2) IN ('LG','LS','NG','NS')

join (select userid , [LG] as grouptype1 , [LS] as grouptype2 , [NG] as grouptype3 , 
[NS] as grouptype4
FROM (SELECT userid , RIGHT(groupname,2) as grouptype FROM #temp) as Sourcetable

PIVOT (MAX(grouptype)
for grouptype in ([LG],[LS],[NG],[NS])) As Pivottable) pt
ON tp.userid = pt.userid
join (select userid, count(*) as cnt from #temp group by userid ) ct
on ct.userid = tp.userid

DROP TABLE #temp

-- Expected Output
 -- 1 Sankar GROUP(LG,LS,NG,NS)
 -- 2 Srini  HYDRSPM(LG,LS)
 -- 3 Ravi   AADSCLS
 -- 4 Arun   RREDFT(LS,NG)
 -- 5 Raja   1234567
 -- 5 Raja   ABCDESLG(LG,LS)
 -- 6 dhilip GGGGRASCDW_RV

rollback
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `FOR XML PATH('')` to concatenate the groups:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0c8d/1/0)

```
SELECT
    t.Userid,
    t.Username,
    Groupname = 'GROUP(' + 
        STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + STUFF(GroupName, 1, 5, '')
            FROM tbl
            WHERE Userid = t.Userid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        , 1, 1, '') + ')'
FROM tbl t
GROUP BY t.Userid, t.Username
DROP TABLE tbl
```

RESULT:

```
| Userid | Username |          Groupname |
|--------|----------|--------------------|
|      1 |   sankar | GROUP(LG,LS,NG,NS) |
|      2 |    Srini |       GROUP(LG,LS) |
|      3 |    Aathi |          GROUP(LS) |
```

Comment: But The Group value is not a constant one.. The Groupname may be like,                                                                                          Userid Username Groupname
1 sankar  HRFDSLG
1 sankar  HRFDSLS
1 sankar  HRFDSNG
1 sankar  HRFDSNS
2 Srini          YAAFRELG
2 Srini          YAAFRELS
3 Aathi          YAAFRELS                                                                                         Only the LG,LS,NG,NS are constant

Comment: and Also the Groupname length value wont be the same for all users.

Comment: I dnt think this is the correct solution as per the requirement, as there is a mismatch between the o/p for 3rd row. Also @SankarM has slightly changed the requirement.

Comment: Hi abhishek, We are almost done the requirment. But, One more problem , Suppose a single user having groupname records ended with 'LG' / 'NG' ...  and also same user having another groupname record without having 'LG' / 'NG'.... That time we have to display Tow rows for a single user.     Example :  5   Abhishek   ABCDEF                                                                               5 Abhishek EDFGC(LG,LS)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `userid + username` combination is unique, please try following query. Also considering that you don't need parenthesis around group in case of a single group, I'v updated the below query.

**explanation:** I've used `STUFF` function  to calculate the grouping of groups with a comma followed by every group code like `LS,LG,`
Now based on comparison of position of comma using `CHARINDEX` with length of string using `LEN`, we attach the logic either adding GROUP() or GROUP to the string

```
   select 
    userid,
    username, 
    CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX(',',groupname)<LEN(groupname) 
        THEN 'GROUP('+ SUBSTRING(groupname,1,LEN(groupname)-1) +')'
        ELSE 'GROUP'+SUBSTRING(groupname,1,LEN(groupname)-1)
    end as groupname 
from 
    (
        select 
          userid, 
          username,
              stuff((
                            select 
                                replace(groupname,'group','') + ',' 
                            from tbl 
                                where 
                                    userid=t.userid and username=t.username 
                            for xml path(''),type).value('.','varchar(max)'),1,0,'')

            as groupname
        from tbl t
        group by userid, username 
    )t
```

and updated 
sql fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21f65/1

gives this exact output

```
  Userid    Username    Groupname
  1             Sankar         GROUP(LG,LS,NG,NS)
  2             Srini          GROUP(LG,LS)
  3             Aathi          GROUPLS
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code snippet -

```
    select a.userid,a.username,
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%,%',a.groupname) > 0 THEN 
     LEFT(a.groupname,PATINDEX('%,%',a.groupname)-3)+'('+REPLACE(a.groupname,LEFT(a.groupname,PATINDEX('%,%',a.groupname)-3),'')+')'         
ELSE a.groupname 
END as groupname 
from
(select userid,username,
    stuff((
        select ',' + t.[Groupname]
        from #users t
        where t.Userid = t1.userid
        order by t.[Groupname]
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as groupname
from #users t1
group by userid,Username) a
```

**Edit:** Changed the code as per the requirement. Please re-check now.

Comment: Hi abhishek, We are almost done the requirment. But, One more problem , Suppose a single user having groupname records ended with 'LG' / 'NG' ... and also same user having another groupname record without having 'LG' / 'NG'.... That time we have to display Tow rows for a single user. Example : 5 Abhishek ABCDEF 5 Abhishek EDFGC(LG,LS)

Comment: @SankarM - please edit the question with the correct i/p data and your desired o/p. I didn't understand wholly your last requirement.

Comment: hi Abhishek i have edited my exact requirement. Please help me on that. I am also looking.